# Triplet loss on text embeddings with keras

Tags: keras, model, word2vec, loss, triplet

I'd start saying i'm quite new to Keras and machine learning in general. I'm trying to build an "experimental" model consisting of two parts:

1. An "encoder" which takes a string (containing a long series of attributes, i'm using the [DBLP-ACM](https://dbs.uni-leipzig.de/en/research/projects/object_matching/benchmark_datasets_for_entity_resolution) dataset), builds an embedding of the words of this string (word2vec), and encodes them in a vector (bidirectional LSTM).
2. A trainable model which takes 3 vectors in input (result of model 1) and uses the triplet loss as loss function (i already defined it, using the euclidean distance between the vectors)

---

My first step was adapting [this model](https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/guide-to-word-vectors-with-gensim-and-keras/) to my dataset, then i created a triplets dataset and i defined the triplet loss function, as i said earlier. I'm now trying to figure out how can i modify this model to accept 3 inputs, distinguishing step 1 and step 2, and applying the proper loss function.

It's quite tricky, but i'm sure is easier than i think. I can provide my actual model, but it's quite similar to the one i linked above (which should represent the first step), except for the input format. Every advice, idea or code snippet is well appreciated!

Comment: I've built an example https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VgOTzr_VZNHkXh2z9IiTAcEgg5qr19y0 But you can probably find plenty of others googling for "keras triplet loss".

Comment: Top hit on google: https://github.com/KinWaiCheuk/Triplet-net-keras

Comment: Thank you, the main problem is that i'm trying to use the triplet loss on texts and i don't need any label, i only need the loss. During the training i should have a 3 input model, and, since i'm using 3 inputs, i need an encoder with shared weights among those 3 inputs. After the training, i should be able to use the same model to evaluate a single input. I'm simply confused, terribly confused

Comment: I think you are on the right track. It is good that you understand that you need a shared encoder and that the loss compares the encoded vectors. If you look at the example I posted above, it works on images, but follows the same principle. Perhaps you can use it as a template. The main idea is that your trained encoder produces a random vector when untrained; the loss causes random vectors that should be similar to come close together while maintaining separation from things that should be different. So it works as an implicit way to do topic decomposition.

Comment: A propos: I would recommend, if you have not done so, to do topic decomposition using sklearn NMF for any dataset that is in the ballpark of 100k docs by 300k tokens or less. It is fast to develop and usually provides excellent results. It gives an excellent baseline to then grow to larger datasets and more complex techniques. reference https://github.com/fastai/course-nlp/blob/master/2-svd-nmf-topic-modeling.ipynb